# How to use doubles and/or integers in toasts?

Tags: java, android, android-toast

I am having trouble trying to use code inside a toast to make it multiply/divide/add/subtract numbers that I input into the app. Keep in mind I am a very beginner in this, any help will be appreciated.

```
Toast toast = new Toast(getApplicationContext());
toast.setGravity(51, 0, 0);
Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, (CelNum * 1.8 + 32), 
  Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
```

If anyone knows what I mean or if there is a better way to do this, please help. Thanks!

Comment: What exactly is the problem? Are you getting an error?

Answer (score 2):

Toast takes a String.  If you want to print a number, you will need to convert it.  Java gives you a couple quick ways to do this:

`"" + 5` or 
`Integer.toString(5)`

Both will convert the 5 to a String.

Comment: Oops, that's what I meant.  I always dislike when people use those terms interchangeably.  Edited for clarification

Answer (score 1):

You must convert your `double` to a `String`. You can use [`String.valueOf`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#valueOf(int))  to convert any primitive type (`int`, `double`, `boolean`, etc.) to a `String`:

```java
Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, String.valueOf(CelNum * 1.8 + 32), 
    Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
```

You can also use [`Integer.toString`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Integer.html#toString(int)) or [`Double.toString`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Double.html#toString(double)), which convert their respective types to `String`.